# How to perform a "from" in Elasticsearch scroll context?

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, pagination, bigdata

I have a large dataset to query and display in website on an array.
I made a pagination system with a scroll but i can only display a maximum of 100 items at a time so  i'm facing issue when i want to display data of page 200 and more because i have to scroll until them and it take too long.

I have check other parts of my code and i didn't find other perf issue, is just the scroll queries which make my api call too long. I tried setting the request size from 100 to 10000 but it doesn't change anything.
I don't think sliced ​​scroll can be a solution or then I didn't understand the functionality.

I'm desperately searching a way to skip the scroll queries before datas that i'm searching even it's not a precise method.

Hoping someone has a solution or at least a clue.

Edit:
More details about what i'm trying to achieve.

I log some actions of my users like calls in Elasticsearch indexes. They do millions of actions per month so Elasticsearch seems like a good option to store them knowing that i don't have to update them after they are stored .

I'm creating a page where my users can search for actions they've performed, but they're doing the "query" themselves. I mean they can select the period and many other parameters, order them by many parameters, etc. The number of result can be 1 or 100,000 items, but I can't show 100,000 items on my page for UI reasons, so I have to manage a pagination and send only part of the result to the page.

I made a scroll query to do it for now with a size of 1000, and i scroll until i'm in the current page of my pagination. I tried to vary the size but it's not really concluent because I can't know the number of result before the query is made.

And the deeper my user go in the pagination, the longer the query take.
I could increase the `index.max_result_window` with an unreachable number (but I don't know what that implies) make a simple query with a from and a second scroll query for export case but I wonder if they are a way to skip some step in a scroll when i know i'm going to take 100 items after the 1 000 000th item ?

Edit: I watched how google design its pagination and i notice that if you want to go deep in search results you can't unless you go step by step. You can't go directly to the 500th page.

[image: Google pagination]

This is how I done mine

[image: My pagination]

So I just redesign my pagination to do the same as Google and force my users to use more precise filters to get less result. Thank you @Val for getting me to ask the right questions :)

Comment: Why do you need to paginate until the a specific page? Why not simply searching for what you need and then paginate on the results? ES is not a database with cursors, but a search engine!

Comment: Hello, it's what i'm doing but my query return too much items so i have to paginate the result

Comment: ES is not a pagination engine, so you'll have to figure out a better way to achieve what you need. The solution might consist of your query, your data, your UI, or a mix of all that. The easy way is to increase `index.max_result_window` to more than 10000, but you'd just be kicking the can down the road and calling for future troubles. Feel free to explain your problem in a bit more details if you want us to help you find a more durable solution.

Comment: I added more context to my question. I will try by increasing `index.max_result_window`. thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you for providing more info. I think the problem is how the users make their queries. Ask them if they are able to browse 100000 results in their Google search results? The key here is to select a small enough period or constraints that restrain the result set to under 10000 results that are easier to page. Eventually, you might want to leverage [`search_after` with a PIT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after)